# CSS automatic horizontal image slideshow seamless transition on restart

Tags: html, css, slideshow

I have an HTML & CSS (only!) automatic horizontal slideshow. Works ok, EXCEPT after the last image is done sliding and the slideshow starts again from the first image, the first image jumps into view abruptly. How do I get this to look more seamless? Is this possible WITHOUT using javascript?

```css
.slider-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 446px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.image-container {
  width: 3240px;
  height: 446px;
  clear: both;
  position: relative;
  animation-name: slider;
  animation-duration: 30s;
  animation-delay: 10s;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-direction: normal;
  animation-fill-mode: backwards;
  animation-play-state: running;
}

.slider-image {
  width: auto;
  height: 446px;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}

@keyframes slider {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
  50% {
      transform: translate(-1080px, 0);
  }
  100% {
      transform: translate(-2160px, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<section class="row top slider-container">
 <div class="image-container">
  <img class="slider-image" src="https://dummyimage.com/1080x446/000/fff.png&text=Image+1" alt="">
  <img class="slider-image" src="https://dummyimage.com/1080x446/333333/fff.png&text=Image+2" alt="">
  <img class="slider-image" src="https://dummyimage.com/1080x446/666666/fff.png&text=Image+3" alt="">
 </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a simple hack and make the 4th image the same image as the first one. You can also do similar to what **Adri1** mentioned but in that case you will see the moving backward to image1.

Here is my solution where the image-1 is repeated as 4th image. Remember you need to increase the width of `.image-container` by 1080 more px and also add another key frame (4 key frames total).

```css
.slider-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 446px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.image-container {
  width: 4320px;
  height: 446px;
  clear: both;
  position: relative;
  animation-name: slider;
  animation-duration: 30s;
  animation-delay: 10s;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-direction: normal;
  animation-fill-mode: backwards;
  animation-play-state: running;
}

.slider-image {
  width: auto;
  height: 446px;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}

@keyframes slider {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
  33% {
      transform: translate(-1080px, 0);
  }
  66% {
      transform: translate(-2160px, 0);
  }
  100% {
      transform: translate(-3240px, 0);
  } 
}
```

```html
<section class="slider-container">
 <div class="image-container">
  <img class="slider-image" src="https://dummyimage.com/1080x446/000/fff.png&text=Image+1" alt="">
  <img class="slider-image" src="https://dummyimage.com/1080x446/333333/fff.png&text=Image+2" alt="">
  <img class="slider-image" src="https://dummyimage.com/1080x446/666666/fff.png&text=Image+3" alt="">
   <img class="slider-image" src="https://dummyimage.com/1080x446/000/fff.png&text=Image+1" alt="">
 </div>
</section>
```

Comment: @pratiba YW, You can verify this answer if it helped. Thanks

Comment: how yo stop it in hover?

Answer (score 0):

Not the best solution, you will have to tweak your timings, but adding a fourth keyframe to scroll back to the first image seems to work.

```css
@keyframes slider {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
  33% {
      transform: translate(-1080px, 0);
  }
  66% {
      transform: translate(-2160px, 0);
  }
  100% {
      transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
}
```